# gnu sort produces different results on MacOS Linux

Tags: linux, macos, sorting, homebrew

I am trying to get the same GNU sort output on MacOS Mavericks and Linux Centos 6.5. I have installed the latest 'brew' gsort on MacOS. I get different output results from the sort on both platforms when sorting exactly the same file: specifically how the '#' character is handled. Here are the first lines of the sorted files where you can see the difference very clearly:

MacOS brew gsort:

```
SENT_ID1###de peu ||| and gustav stresemann ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID1###en compagnie d' aristide briand ||| only just missed achieving ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID1###et de gustav stresemann ||| their aim ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID1###il a manqué cet objectif ||| he and aristide briand ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID10###dans le même esprit ||| still ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID10###de comblement ||| with the same aim of making good ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID10###de nos institutions européennes ||| of institutional democracy ||| 1.0<br/>
```

etc.

Same file on CentOS with 'sort':

```
SENT_ID10000###car il constitue l' ||| as it constitutes ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID10000###de ce débat ||| of this debate ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID10000###nous pensons ||| we think ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID10000###que ce paragraphe aurait mérité ||| that this section would have merited ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID10000###un des défis majeurs ||| one of the major challenges ||| 1.0<br/>

SENT_ID10000###un plus ample développement ||| further development ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID10001###à aucune règle si ce n' est celle du marché ||| only to market rules ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID10001###ces systèmes complémentaires ||| these supplementary systems ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID10001###en augmentation ||| which are increasing ||| 1.0<br/>
SENT_ID10001###ne sont soumis ||| are subject ||| 1.0<br/>
```

etc.

The zero character has precedence over 'hash' character in sort terms under CentOS and as you can see the sort order is completely different. The gsort MacOS sort order is the one I would expect. Can anyone enlighten me as to why the CentOS sort order is wrong and how I can correct this?

Comment: Can you run `set | grep LC` on each system and post the results?

Comment: HI John, zilch on both systems - I do not have a LC environment set on either MacOS nor CenTOS

Comment: See output of `locale` on both systems.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen different behavior on macOS vs Linux even when `locale` on both systems is apparently the same.

If you use `LC_COLLATE=C` or `LC_COLLATE=POSIX`, it should at least be consistent across the two operating systems.

**macOS, `fr_FR.UTF-8`:**

```sh
$ (export LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8; echo -e 'a\nA\na.1\nA.1\na1\nA1\na#1\nA#1' | gsort)
A
A#1
A.1
A1
a
a#1
a.1
a1
```

Note capital letters sort before lower case, `#` sorts before `.` and `.` before `1`.

**Linux (RH6), `fr_FR.utf8`:**

```sh
$ (export LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.utf8; echo -e 'a\nA\na.1\nA.1\na1\nA1\na#1\nA#1' | sort)
a
A
a1
a.1
a#1
A1
A.1
A#1
```

Note capital letters sort after lower case, `1` sorts before `.` and `.` before `#`.

Now with `POSIX`:

**macOS:**

```sh
$ (export LC_COLLATE=POSIX; echo -e 'a\nA\na.1\nA.1\na1\nA1\na#1\nA#1' | gsort)
A
A#1
A.1
A1
a
a#1
a.1
a1
```

**Linux:**

```sh
$ (export LC_COLLATE=POSIX; echo -e 'a\nA\na.1\nA.1\na1\nA1\na#1\nA#1' | sort)
A
A#1
A.1
A1
a
a#1
a.1
a1
```

Interestingly, the macOS default collations seem much closer to the POSIX standard. I'd like to know the history behind that.